# Magento2: gettig error in git while running upgrade command

Tags: magento2

I am getting issue after running upgrade command.

```
The "/mnt/data/home/abc/vdmmezbtxm/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/App/Request/PathInfoProcessor/Proxy.php" file can't be deleted. Warning!unlink(/mnt/data/home/abc/vdmmezbtxm/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/App/Request/PathInfoProcessor/Proxy.php): Permission denied The "/mnt/data/home/abc/vdmmezbtxm/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Proxy.php" file can't be deleted. Warning!unlink(/mnt/data/home/abc/vdmmezbtxm/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/Proxy.php): Permission denied The "/mnt/data/home/abc/vdmmezbtxm/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom/Proxy.php" file can't be deleted. Warning!unlink(/mnt/data/home/abc/vdmmezbtxm/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom/Proxy.php): Permission denied
```

Also getting error php bin/magento list

```
In ServiceManager.php line 1130:

  An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentosetupconsolecomm
  andbackupcommand(alias: Magento\Setup\Console\Command\BackupCommand).


In ServiceManager.php line 941:

  An exception was raised while creating "Magento\Setup\Console\Command\Backu
  pCommand"; no instance returned


In Di.php line 865:

  Missing instance/object for parameter maintenanceMode for Magento\Setup\Con
  sole\Command\BackupCommand::__construct


In ServiceManager.php line 1130:

  An abstract factory could not create an instance of magentoframeworkappmain
  tenancemode(alias: Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode).


In ServiceManager.php line 941:

  An exception was raised while creating "Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMo
  de"; no instance returned


In ClassReader.php line 19:

  Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Interceptor does not exist
```

please check

Comment: give 777 permission to /generated folder

Comment: Not able to give-------------
master_xtmqndbjgg is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: Please delete generated folder and then run upgrade command.

Comment: I have deleted but its not working

Comment: Getting this issue----while running upgrade command ---There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

Comment: Also updated my question

Comment: @ChiragGondaliya please check

Comment: Please try this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935850/there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the-setup-namespace-magento-2